# Data transformation after successful validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, normalization, validation, model-validation

I'm having a bit of a problem normalizing a UPC string code so that I can store it in the same format in the database.

I'm using the `ean` gem to check if the string is good (which is working fine), but if I throw some assignment code after it validates such as:

```
validate :upc_check

def upc_check
    if !upc.nil?
        if !upc.ean?
            errors.add(:upc, 'is not a valid UPC.')
        else
            upc = upc.strip
        end 
    end 
end
```

The strip call is just an example as it's a string. I'll actually be removing the dashes in the upc.

The above code doesn't work so well as it doesn't actually save it. I had a look at triggering a method like

```
after_validation :normalize_upc

def normalize_upc
    upc = upc.strip
end
```

..but the above doesn't work either.

What do you guys do to validate and transform data after validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make my validator strict, and then use a before_validation filter to do any necessary transformations.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend overriding the setter method in your model for upc and not having a separate method for normalizing it. This would be accomplished with something like:

```
def upc=(value)
  self.upc = value.strip
end
```

Edit:

I would also clean up your validation method to remove this functionality like so:

```
validate :upc_check, :unless => lambda {|m| m.upc.nil?}

def upc_check
  errors.add(:upc, 'is not valid') unless upc.ean?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried the above but when I try to set it from the console, then it gives me a `stack level too deep` error. Thoughts?

Comment: My bad its just going to keep calling the setter method with what I wrote. Change self.upc to super(value.strip) or use write_attribute

Comment: Thanks, it works! Either method works, but I ended up going with @fullware simply because I saw his answer before your edited comment. I wish there was a way to indicate an equivalent answer :D